# Tridion Docs 15 Web Services API: Find Topics not being referenced (orphan)

Tags: api, tridion-docs

We need to create a report of all Topic that are not referenced in any other DocumentObject.

Is there a DocumentObject's metadata field that keeps track of references to itself? Is there a way to use `API25.Search.PerformSearch` to query for such metadata field?

Thanks for your assistance.